# What file on memory stick ISO will boot into the setup menu

Tags: boot, system-installation, uefi

I purchased an Dell Inspirion 14-3452 laptop. It has a 32G emmc chip with Windows 10 on it. I am trying to replace Windows 10 with Lubuntu 18.4. I burned an ISO to a 4G flash drive. A YouTube video I watched recommended disabling "Secure Boot", "Load Legacy Option", and "Firmware TPM" in the Bios.  I need to add a boot option to replace boot option #1. This requires two items; a name and file name including path.  The video showed the author used  the file name [UBUNTU], but didn't provide a file name or path on the flash drive. Can anyone provide that information?